# How can I customize which tags I see in my Super User news feed?

Tags: support

I am new to Super User and not familiar with all questions. Is it possible to follow specific topics/tags so that I can see only them in my questions/newsfeed?

Comment: Go to tags and select which tag you are familiar with or type in search and find the tag.

Comment: @vembutech that way, I can see questions with one tag at once, however, I was wondering if features such as "topics" in Quora is also available here in Superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can set up a list of "favorite" tags. Click the "edit" link under the Favorite Tags heading on the right of the main site's homepage; there you can add and remove tags as your favorites. Here's what mine look like:

[image: my favorite tags]

Once you add some tags and reload the page, questions with at least one of your favorite tags will get a blue highlight.

[image: one of my favorite tags on a question]

If you want to see *only* unanswered questions with your favorite tags, go to the ["my tags" tab of the Unanswered page](https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags).

If you want an RSS feed of a given tag's questions, go to the tag page (click the tag; [here's the [windows] one](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) as an example) and scroll to the bottom. You'll find a link to a feed with the tag's newest questions.

[image: windows rss]